# Why is output only odd or even numbers from a Python iterator?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I have a problem using an iterator in Python. I want to print only the numbers 1 to 20, but my code gives me the odd or even numbers only. Why is this occurring?

I also tried by tracking it, but still I don't get the answer I expect.

```
class mynumbers:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 1
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        #print(a)   for tracking purpose
        if(self.a<=20):
            x = self.a
            self.a +=1
            #print('loop1')
            return x
        else:
            #print('loop2')
            raise StopIteration

myclass = mynumbers()
myiter = iter(myclass)
for y in myiter:
    print(next(myiter))
```

This program prints even numbers. If I change the value `a` to 0 then it gives odd numbers. But I want all numbers like 1,2,3,...20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
for y in myiter:
    print(next(myiter))
```

There's no need to call `next()`, which is causing every other element to be skipped. Just use:

```
for y in myiter:
    print(y)
```

and `next()` is called under the hood for you.

A case when you might use `next()` directly is when you're outside of a loop construct:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> it = combinations("abcd", 2)
>>> next(it)
('a', 'b')
>>> next(it)
('a', 'c')
>>> # some time later...
... next(it)
('a', 'd')
>>> # some time later, exhaust the rest:
... list(it)
[('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration, the `__next__` function prints the next number & then increments it.

This skips the starting number & it's types (odd/ even)

What you need to do is, either print/ return the element from the `__iter__` function or increment it within the `__iter__` and print it using the current method.